# Unity Scripting missing definition for a variable and a unassigned local variable c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am fairly new to unity and game scripting and I am having problems starting out.

This is my playstate.cs (I am only pasting the relevant code lines)

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using Assets.Code.Scripts;
using System.Collections;  // dicionario
using System.Collections.Generic;  // dicionario

namespace Assets.Code.States

            gametime = (int)Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / 5;                                

            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 650, 10, 100, 25), gametime.ToString() );  // GAME TIME HOURS

            float test;

            if (LoadDiagram.diagramaCarga.TryGetValue(gametime, out test)) // Returns true.
            {
                GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 650, 275, 50, 25),  test.ToString ());
            }
```

And this is where my LoadDiagram is stored:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;
using System.Collections;  // dicionario
using System.Collections.Generic;  // dicionario
using System;
namespace Assets.Code.Scripts
{
    public class LoadDiagram 
    {
        public LoadDiagram ()
        {
            Dictionary<int, float> diagramaCarga = new Dictionary<int, float>();

            diagramaCarga.Add(0, 4.2F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(1, 4F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(2, 3.6F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(3, 3.4F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(4, 3.2F);
            diagramaCarga.Add(5, 3F);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have two errors:

error CS0117: `Assets.Code.Scripts.LoadDiagram' does not contain a definition for`diagramaCarga'

error Assets/Code/States/PlayState.cs(112,87): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `test'

Have any idea of what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `diagramaCarga` only exists inside the local scope (inside the curly braces) of the `LoadDiagram()` constructor method. You need create a public property or field for it inside the class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, @cubrr's comment is correct, but he didn't put it as an answer.

> `diagramaCarga` only exists inside the local scope (inside the curly braces) of the `LoadDiagram()` constructor method. You need create a public property or field for it inside the class scope.

More specifically, you are trying to access it as a *static* field inside your other class, which means you would need the `LoadDiagram` class to look like this:

```
public class LoadDiagram 
{
    public static Dictionary<int, float> diagramaCarga = new Dictionary<int, float>();
    // this is a "static block" which acts like a constructor for static objects,
    // as static classes do not use constructors.
    // If I got the syntax correct, I've never actually used one of these.
    static LoadDiagram(){ // !!edited this line!!
        diagramaCarga.Add(0, 4.2F);
        diagramaCarga.Add(1, 4F);
        diagramaCarga.Add(2, 3.6F);
        diagramaCarga.Add(3, 3.4F);
        diagramaCarga.Add(4, 3.2F);
        diagramaCarga.Add(5, 3F);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you removed this line: public LoadDiagram () ? It is not working yet I have also added the 2 extra curly braces

Comment: I did a little more than that.

Comment: I get this now: Unexpected symbol `(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: It happens several times, one time for each line of the dictionary.

Comment: `*`Googles about for a minute`*` Ah, I had some incorrect syntax, check the edited answer.  Only one line changed.

Comment: Now I get this: An object reference is required to access non-static member

Comment: Oh, whoops, forgot to mark the field as static too. `public static Dictionary<int, float>....`

Comment: Got it can you update the answer to help other people?

Comment: The only dictionary..?  I also edited my answer, which only contains one instance of "public static".